# Random Integer: Android

Tags: java, android

I'm guessing this is very simple, but for some reason I am unable to figure it out. So, how do you pick a random integer out of two numbers. I want to randomly pick an integer out of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the standard uniform random distribution, sample it, if it's less than 0.5 choose one value, if it's greater, choose the other:

```
 int randInt = new Random().nextDouble() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `nextInt` method which takes as input a cap (exclusive in the range) on the size and then offset to account for it returning 0 (the inclusive minimum):

```
int randInt = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

use following function:

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    Random r = new Random();
    if(r.nextInt(2)) return a;
    else return b;
}
```

This will return a or b with uniform distribution.
That means in a very simple way: If you run this function N times, expected occurrence of 'a' and 'b' are N/2 each.